# MySQL into output file error

Tags: mysql, csv, into-outfile

I am very new with SQL but I have to extract some fields of a table stored in  a sql file.

I  have installed mysql and create the database and source the file. Now I wanted to execute a sql request in order to read all the elts of the table, extract the interesting fields and write them into cvs file:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/home/cr/database/Dump2/program_info.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM program_info;
```

When running the command I have the following error message:

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Does anyone knows how to solve it ?
I have struggled with this message all the afternoon but could not .

I am working on Linux ubuntu and my config file is /etc/my.cfg

> [mysqld]
>   read-only                      = 0
>   secure-file-priv               = ""

Thank you for your help

Comment: check the mysqld command line. just because the directive isn't in the .ini/.cnf file doesn't mean it can't be specified elsewhere.

Comment: How do I "check the mysqld" ? BR

Comment: `ps auxwww|grep mysqld`

Comment: Thank you, running your command  I have the following output:  `mysql    29141  0.1  1.1 1915592 183236 ?      Ssl  16:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
`

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is actually working as intended. The MySQL server booted with the --secure-file-priv option which basically restricts you from saving output into random directories. You need to check the startup parameters.

To do so, run the following command in the MySQL shell:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';
```

The output would be what the MySQL Server currently thinks is the permitted location. You should be able to save your output to this location.

To disable the restriction, you need to edit the configuration file that declares it and restart the MySQL Server after changing the option.

MySQL could be reading the my.ini (or my.cnf) configuration file from a variety of locations. See [Using Option Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) for more information.

Comment: My files are outputting to the secure_file_priv location, but is it possible to put 2 subfolders in that directory and have it output to those? Currently it gives me a "permission denied" message but I'm not sure if there is a workaround so that I can export 2 different data sets to 2 locations, as they are ultimately still inside the secure_file_priv directory.